# Cannot control joint from pygazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I am trying to control a joint from the following world file: [exported.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14358513227974385.world)

While I can move the joint with the following command via terminal

> gz joint -m 'default_body' -j hingejoint0 -f 10000

I cannot move the same joint with the following python script using PyGazebo:

```
import trollius
from trollius import From

import pygazebo
import pygazebo.msg.joint_cmd_pb2

@trollius.coroutine
def publish_loop():
    manager = yield From(pygazebo.connect())

    publisher = yield From(
        manager.advertise('/gazebo/default/model/joint_cmd',
                          'gazebo.msgs.JointCmd'))

    message = pygazebo.msg.joint_cmd_pb2.JointCmd()
    message.name = 'default_bot::hingejoint0'
    #message.axis = 0
    message.force = 10000

    while True:
        yield From(publisher.publish(message))
        yield From(trollius.sleep(1.0))

loop = trollius.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(publish_loop())
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I sending the command to the wrong endpoint? is my message improperly formatted?

I am using Gazebo 4.1.0 on Ubuntu with the Simbody physics engine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9042/cannot-control-joint-from-pygazebo/) by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe you are advertising on the wrong topic. Try:

```
manager.advertise('/gazebo/world/default_body/joint_cmd', 'gazebo.msgs.JointCmd'))
```

The topic name is /gazebo/WORLD_NAME/MODEL_NAME/join_cmd. In your case `WORLD_NAME`="world", and `MODEL_NAME`="default_body", based on your SDF file.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Skylion](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1252/skylion/) on 2015-07-02**:
Thank you, I just submitted a pull request to the repo to update their example code for those unfamiliar with how topics are generated.